# Reducing filenames in a directory and renaming them in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Extreme newbie here! I have multiple images (jpg) which have very long wordy filenames. I want to reduce the filenames to the first six digits. So I'm thinking they need to go into an array to enable the count along. Complication is, there can be more than one image per product, so I need to count and add ~1, ~2 etc.

Examples: Original filename:

110312_Classic Colour colour pencils cardboard wallet 16 pieces_Office_67779.jpg
110312_Classic Colour colour pencils cardboard wallet 16 pieces_Office_52779.jpg

How I need them to be:
110312~1.jpg
110312~2.jpg

Thanks!

To be honest, I've only just started my Ruby course, so haven't managed to put any code together yet.

Comment: `110312~2.jpg` This looks like MSDOS from 30 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```rb
Dir.glob("<your global path to the image directory>/**/*.jpg").each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |file_path, acc|
  # get filename without global path
  filename = File.basename(file_path, '.jpg')
  # match first 6 characters
  new_filename = filename[0...6]
  # counter how many duplicates for index names
  # NOTE. Passed Hash.new(0) as the #each_of_object argument always returns 0 for a non-existent key.
  # Ex:
  # hash = Hash.new(5) => {}
  # hash['foo'] = 'bar' => 'bar'
  # hash['non_existed_key'] => 5
  # hash['foo'] => 'bar'
  acc[new_filename] += 1
  # collect full name with global file path
  new_filepath = "#{File.dirname(file_path)}/#{new_filename}~#{acc[new_filename]}.jpg"
  # rename the file
  File.rename(file_path, new_filepath)
end
```

Dir.glob('.../**/*') matches nested directories as well. if you don't need them you do Dir.glob('.../*')